# Splitting Filename delimited by period (.)

Tags: awk, sh

I'm writting an sh file where I have var as:

```
c=aabbcc.DP.09-25-2012_14_17.dmp
```

i want to copy only initial part in another var like:

```
d = aabbcc
```

How should I trim my var?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If by `sh` you mean `bash`, then

```
d="${c%%.*}"
```

otherwise

```
d="`echo "$d"|cut -d. -f1`"
```

will do, perhaps.

Comment: No, i'm sorry, i'm using Shell Script. (.sh) Can you help me please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it's a shell script, the question is what shell you're using. Just try both solution and see if it works.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, the better ;) I can never remember what is bashism and what is not.

Answer (score 9):

perl:

```
D=`echo $c | perl -lne 's/([^\.]*)\..*/\1/;print'`
```

sed:

```
D=`echo $c | sed 's/\([^\.]*\)\..*/\1/'`
```

awk:

```
D=`echo $c | awk -F. '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 2):

The expr command is compatible with any sh implementation and does not need pipes

```
d=`expr $c : '\([^\.]*\)'`
```